# What is needed to use 1 central certificate authority for all the organization on Hyperledger Fabric v1.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Based on Hyperldeger Fabric  is created a network on which there are:1 orderer, 1 ca, 1 couchdb, 1 cli, 1 peer

Afterwards, is added a new org with: 1 peer, 1 couchdb and 1 cli

Until this stage there is no error. All the containers are running. Then is enrolled the ca admin. Still no problem. The admin is connected with no problem. I want to create admin for the new organization.

enrollandregisterNewAdmin.js

```
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        const ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
        const adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();       
        const secret = await ca.register({
            affiliation: 'org1.department1',
            enrollmentID: 'adminOrg3',
            role: 'client',
            attrs: [ {"name": "hf.Registrar.Roles", "value": "client"}, 
                {"name": "hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles", "value": "client"}, 
                {"name": "hf.Revoker", "value": "true"},
                {"name": "hf.IntermediateCA", "value": "true"}, 
                {"name": "hf.GenCRL", "value": "true"}, 
                {"name": "hf.AffiliationMgr", "value": "true"}, 
                {"name": "hf.Registrar.Attributes", "value": "hf.Registrar.Roles,hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles,hf.Revoker,hf.IntermediateCA,hf.GenCRL,hf.Registrar.Attributes,hf.AffiliationMgr"} ] }
        , adminIdentity);

        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'adminOrg3', enrollmentSecret: secret});    
        const userIdentity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org3MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
        await wallet.import('adminOrg3', userIdentity);
```

Finally the certificates of 'adminOrg3' are imported to the wallet with no error. But when I am trying to invoke/query with the 'adminOrg3'. I receive this error:

**[Channel.js]: Channel:byfn received discovery error:access denied
[Channel.js]: Error: Channel:byfn Discovery error:access denied
error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:byfn Discovery error:access denied**

This is a common error when the wallet exists from a previous deployment. But the wallet is deleted each time the network is restarted.

docker logs peer0.org3.example.com

```
2021-02-22 10:21:09.588 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 082 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 0
```

My config file for new org
docker-compose-org3.yaml

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  peer0.org3.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  peer0.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:11052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 11051:11051
    networks:
      - byfn

  Org3cli:
    container_name: Org3cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=Org3cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./org3-artifacts/crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com
         -./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    depends_on:
      - peer0.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Is it possible under the same affiliation to exist different MSPs?

Is needed any change to the configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify few things ...

- did you add the new org on the channel before trying to connect with the new org user?
- are you running the peers in docker containers and use volumes for the peer file system mapping? - It may happen that the peers still load the content of the old channels...

-Tsvetan

Comment: Yes the new org joined the channel and the chaincodes are installed. Yes, i am using dockers. How to map the peers? I updated my question with the config of the new org

Comment: How do you restart the network exactly? If your crypto is regenerated when restarting the network then that may cause issues with the channel that was there before the restart as you map the production folder of the peer to local docker volume (peer0.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production). So when the peer starts again it will load the old channel with the old certs and if you use a new user registered and enroll by new CA it will not work. If you delete the volume though you will have to rejoin the org3 to the channel again.

Comment: @ Tsvetan Georgiev i do not restart the network when i add the new org. I am using cryptogen to generate cert for the new org. The deployment is based on first network. So what is your suggestion?

Comment: @HectorCode To make sure I get it right: you use cryptogen to generate the certs for the new org. Then you join the new org on the channel (by signing the transaction update with the admin users of two orgs currently on the channel and commiting the transaction the channel). I guess the Fabric CA of the new org is using the PKI as generated by crypto gen and used to include include on the channel update? The best is to make sure that the new org CA root cert is on the ledger and it is exactly the one used to sign the cert of the new user you are using to connect.